# Solr master(replication) version never reaches master(searching) version for one core

Tags: solr, replication

We have installed a replicated Solr with four cores; one master receiving all writes, and one or more slaves replicating from the master. For all but one of these cores all works fine.

One core show a very special behaviour on the master. Write operations on it change the master(searching) version shown in the Solr admin, but the master(replication) never changes. So the slaves never get noted about changes in the master core; only for this one core; the three others do not show this problem. This is quite strange, as the replication configuration is shared between all four cores.

```
<requestHandler class="solr.ReplicationHandler" name="/replication" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="master">
            <str name="enable">${enable.master:false}</str>
            <str name="replicateAfter">startup</str>
            <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
            <str name="replicateAfter">optimize</str>
            <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,solrconfig_admin.xml,solrconfig_highlighter.xml,solrconfig_logging.xml,solrconfig_indexconfig.xml,solrconfig_matchversion.xml,solrconfig_query.xml,solrconfig.xml,stopwords.txt
            </str>
            <str name="commitReserveDuration">00:00:10</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="slave">
            <str name="enable">${enable.slave:false}</str>
            <str name="masterUrl">${replication.master.url}</str>
            <str name="pollInterval">00:00:30</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

The parameters `replication.master.url`, `enable.master` and `enable.slave` are defined in the solrcore.properties in the respective core/conf directories.

We use Solr 4.5.1.